# License plate restriction question about C: some examples are not work properly

Tags: c, debugging, licensing, restriction

Here's my question:
Vehicles are restricted for activities held in a place:
Enter a line of five characters to represent the license plate number.
The number can be 0 to 9 digits or uppercase letters, and at least one digit.
Output "illegal input" in the following cases:

1. Enter more than five characters
2. No numbers appear
3. Other characters appear
   If the last digit is odd, output "traffic limit"; Otherwise, output "Pass".

I tested a few examples and they all passed, but the program didn't work in some cases that I didn't know about, and I wanted to know why.
Could you give a counter example or point out the error of my program?
Thank you very much.
And I'm using VS2022 as my editor and Windows 10 as my operating system
Below is an example of my test success and my code:

```
Example 1: 
input: AbC13<enter key>
output: illegal input
Example 2:
input: AB12C<enter key>
output: Pass
Example 3:
input: 11111<enter key>
output: traffic limit
Example 4:
input: 22222<enter key>
output: Pass
Example 5:
input: QQQQQ<enter key>
output: illegal input
Example 6:
input: AAAA1<enter key>
output: traffic limit
Example 7:
input: BBBB2<enter key>
output: Pass
Example 8:
input: FFQ1A<enter key>
output: Pass
Example 9:
input: QQTS5S<enter key>
output: illegal input
Example 10:
input: 5aA<enter key>
output: illegal input
Example 11:
input:.wqe123<enter key>
output: illegal input
Example 12:
input:,-=-+<enter key>
output: illegal input
Example 13:
input:0123456789<enter key>
output: illegal input
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char lic[10] = { 0 };
    //lic Array used to store the input character
    int flag = 0, i = 0, j, num = 0, odd = 0;
    //flag Used to record whether a number appears 
    //There is a number when flag = 1
    //num Used to record the number of times no other characters have appeared
    //odd Used to record whether the last occurrence of the number is an odd number
    //The last number is odd when odd = 1
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &lic[i]);
        if (lic[i] == '\n')
        {
            break;//When the input "\n" exit the cycle
        }
    }
    if (lic[5] != 0 && lic[5] != 10)//ASCII "10" on behalf of the carriage return, that is, '\ n'
    {
        flag = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (lic[j] <= '9' && lic[j] >= '0')
            {
                flag = 1;
                num++;
            }
            if (lic[j] <= 'Z' && lic[j] >= 'A')
            {
                num++;
            }
        }
        if ((lic[4] <= '9' && lic[4] >= '0') && (lic[4] % 2))
        {
            odd = 1;
        }
    }
    if (num == 5 && flag == 1)
    {
        (odd) ? (printf("traffic limit\n")) : (printf("Pass\n"));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("illegal input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question talks about the C language, so why the C++ tag?  If you are coding in C++, switch to `std::string`, you'll be thankful you did.

Comment: Not going to lie - that is some weird code in there, What does (j = j) do? And that's the least of it.

Comment: Since you tagged as C, try using a string specifier for [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).  Something like `scanf("%10s", lic);`

Comment: Very bad form to use the trenary operator ( `?:` ) instead of `if/else`... Who wants to try to read this sort of thing? `j = j` in order to jam the trenary operator into a place where a simple `if()` would be appropriate... Start there...

Comment: You must construct some basic tests to stress your algorithm. For instance, at a minimum I would try: all digits, _odd_ digits, _even_ digits, mixture of odd/even, no digits, last digit even, last digit odd, start with letter, end with letter, too many characters, too few characters, invalid character. If you do all this, I think you'll find your code treats a lot of valid inputs as invalid.

Comment: Note also that your interpretation of "last digit is odd" might be incorrect. Technically, I expect the "last digit" is not necessarily the last _character_. It's simply the right-most character that happens to be a digit.

Comment: Please  post exact input used - including the <enter key>

Comment: As a novice and non-native English speaker, I may have a limited understanding of the rules and grammar here. Please bear with me if I have made any mistakes. In addition, I have revised my questions in response to some questions in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments, I have found the mistake, I have a problem understanding the topic, as mentioned in the comment.
I modified my program for this purpose and now it works properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char lic[10] = { 0 };
    //lic Array used to store the input character
    int flag = 0, i = 0, j, num = 0, odd = 0,temp = 0;
    //flag Used to record whether a number appears  
    //There is a number when flag = 1
    //num Used to record the number of times no other characters have appeared
    //odd Used to record whether the last occurrence of the number is an odd number
    //The last number is odd when odd = 1
    gets(lic);
    if (lic[5] != 0&&lic[5]!=10)//ASCII "10" on behalf of the carriage return, that is, '\ n'
    {
        flag = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (lic[j] <= '9' && lic[j] >= '0')
            {
                flag = 1;
                temp = lic[j];
                num++;
            }
            if (lic[j] <= 'Z' && lic[j] >= 'A')
            {
                num++;
            }
        }
        if ((temp <= '9' && temp >= '0') && (temp % 2))
        {
            odd = 1;
        }
    }
    if (num == 5&& flag == 1)
    {
        (odd) ? (printf("traffic limit\n")) : (printf("Pass\n"));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("illegal input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```